# Html and body height are not 100%

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile page. Even I set the 100% on html and body, the height of html and body is still not the same as its content container (landing-container). For this jsfiddle example, its body's height is about 300px but landing-container's height is about 1600px. I am using Chrome. Why does it happen and is there any workaround?

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

<html>
<body>
<div id="holder" data-role="page" data-theme="none" data-ajax="false">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="landing-container">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can check it out here.
http://jsfiddle.net/angelohuang/brbqh/4/

Comment: Are you talking about content height because html and body height don't count in jQuery Mobile?

Comment: If you looks at the ui-page element #holder's height, it is 100%. However, body and html doesn't cover it 100%, but only top portion. I assume the parent should has the same height as child content's height.

Comment: Problem is, it is hard to see in your example what is that you want. Can you create a simple jsFiddle example, or at least clean some HTML.

Comment: I just cleaned up jsfiddle example to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its maybe because you have `position: absolute` on some stuff?

Absolute positioning takes the element out of the normal layout flow, and therefore it isn't affecting its parents' height.

Looks like jQuery mobile is adding many of these styles as a result of the `data-role` stuff. I'm not familiar with jQuery mobile personally, but perhaps you're using it in a non-standard way?

**EDIT**

Oh, hahah.  This would do it too:

```
.ui-mobile, .ui-mobile body {
  height: 99.9%;
}
```

that way it never gets more than the window height, unless I'm confused.

Comment: You are right. If I comment out position: absolute from landing-container css attributes, its parent (.holder) now contains all height of children. However, body and html is still shorter. I don't think it's 99.9%, because the difference is more than 1000px.

Comment: what happens if you change that to `height: auto;`? I'm not suggesting that its the `0.1%` discrepency, but that the percent will be relative to the window height (visible on screen) rather than its contents.